# NetworkImageView with InfoWindowAdapter

Tags: android, android-volley

I'm having trouble trying to use Volley's `NetworkImageView` with an `InfoWindow` of Google Maps API v2.

My markers shows an InfoWindow with an image fetched from the internet. As you know, the only way to do this is to show the InfoWindow and refresh it when finished downloading the image.

So I need a way to know when the NetworkImageView have finished downloading the image so I can refresh that view.

I'm looking for something like *onLoadComplete*

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Modify `NetworkImageView`

```java
public void setImageUrl(String url, ImageLoader imageLoader, ImageListener myListener) {
        mUrl = url;
        mImageLoader = imageLoader;
        // The URL has potentially changed. See if we need to load it.
        loadImageIfNecessary(false, myListener);
}

/** @param myListener notified when image has loaded or on error */
private void loadImageIfNecessary(final boolean isInLayoutPass, final ImageListener myListener) {
...
ImageContainer newContainer = mImageLoader.get(mUrl,
                new ImageListener() {
                 @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        if (myListener != null) {
                            myListener.onErrorResponse(error);
                        }
                        if (mErrorImageId != 0) {
                            setImageResource(mErrorImageId);
                        }
                    }
                ... 
                @Override
                    public void onResponse(final ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                    ...
                     if (response.getBitmap() != null) {
                            if (myListener != null) {
                                myListener.onResponse(response, false); // pay attention to boolean isImmediate param
                            }
                            setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
                            ...
                    }
                }
            }
            ...
```

Now you can use it in your `Adapter` or any other code:

```java
public void bind(Item item) {
    imageView.setImageUrl(imageUrl, app.getImageLoader(), new ImageListener() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
            // isImmediate == true - taken from cache
            // isImmediate == false - successfully loaded from server
        }

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a a custom NetworkImageView as oleksandr_yefremow suggested and got it working although the cache is not working by some reason.

```
public View getInfoWindow(final Marker marker) {

final CustomImageView imageView = ...
imageView.setImageUrl(imageUrl, app.getImageLoader(), new ImageListener() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(response.getBitmap());
        marker.showInfoWindow();
        // isImmediate == true - taken from cache
        // isImmediate == false - successfully loaded from server
    }

    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) { }
});
```

}